# Resolve ValueError when using random choice from a list with restrictions

Tags: python, numpy, random, valueerror

Given a random list and a restriction list:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.random.randint(0, 50, 10)
>>> x
array([27, 14, 42,  1,  9, 43, 16, 39, 27,  3])
>>> y = [1,2,5, 19, 27]
>>> n = 5
```

And I want to sample (without replacement) N out of X without the values in Y, I could do something like this:

```
>>> np.random.choice(list(set(x).difference(y)), n, replace=False)
array([39,  9, 43, 14, 16])
```

N is a user-input that is surely less then `len(x)` but given that I've no idea whether N is bigger than the subset of X-Y, I might get this situation that throws a `ValueError`:

```
>>> np.random.choice(list(set(x).difference(y)), 8, replace=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1150, in mtrand.RandomState.choice (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:18113)
ValueError: Cannot take a larger sample than population when 'replace=False'
```

Given that I would have to preset a max value for N, e.g.:

```
>>> n = min(n, len(list(set(x).difference(y))) )
>>> n
7
```

But in that case N is no longer 8, which the user inputs:

```
>>> np.random.choice(list(set(x).difference(y)), n, replace=False)
array([14, 39, 43,  3, 42,  9, 16])
```

So I have to post-add the output:

```
>>> list(np.random.choice(list(set(x).difference(y)), _n, replace=False)) + [-1]*(n-_n)
[43, 42, 9, 16, 3, 39, 14, -1]
```

To summarize, I have to sample N no. of elements without replacement from a subset of values of X that isn't in Y and I need to fill up the "gaps" with -1 if the length of the subset is less than N.

**I could do it with the code above but is there a less verbose (hopefully also more efficient) way to achieve the same output?**

Comment: BTW, `[-1]*(n-_n)` looks an emoji.

Comment: I would imagine that `np.where` could be use in filtering out the Y in X [https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html] but I'm not sure whether it's as helpful as `list(set(x).difference(y))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to take the difference, and then `np.append` for post processing:

```
x = np.random.randint(0, 50, 10)
y = [1, 2, 5, 19, 27]
n = 12    

x_y = x[~np.in1d(x,y)]                                                    
arr = np.append(np.random.choice(x_y, len(x_y), replace=False), [-1]*(n-len(x_y)))
print arr
# array([35, 46, 39, 21,  9, 37, 17, 23,  8, -1, -1, -1])
```

If `n` is less than the length of the difference, nothing gets appended.

Comment: In your code, what is the type of `y`? I'm getting `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

Comment: Ah, got it, it's not that `y` needs to be an `np.array`, it's `x` needs to be an array to use the index retrieving of the `np.in1d` =)